# How do I add select polyfills using Babel 7 and Gulp?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, gulp, babeljs

I recently upgraded to Babel 7 using Gulp 4. After deploying my code, I realized there are IE 11 compatibility issues, and also issues with early versions of Microsoft Edge browser (16, 17, 18) where a `Symbol is undefined` is returned. I'm not using much ES6 in my code yet, but am using features like `.includes()`, `.startsWith.()`, and the `Spread` syntax. I need to add some polyfills for this purpose, but all of my attempts at doing this have been unsuccessful.

The compiled code is just plain old JS file used on a website, and is not part of a React build or anything.

**package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/register": "^7.8.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "del": "^5.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-babel": "^8.0.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-eslint": "^6.0.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-terser": "^1.2.0"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.4",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15"
}
```

**gulpfile.babel.js** (including only the function used for the build task)

```
function createBuildTask(destination) {
    var sourceArray = [ // simplified for this posting
        'file1.js', 'file2.js', 'file3.js', 'file4.js'
    ];

    return function () {
        return gulp.src(sourceArray, {'allowEmpty': true})
            .pipe(babel({
                'presets': ['@babel/preset-env'],
                'plugins': []
            }))
            .pipe(concat('desktop-built.js'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('desktop/dist'))
            .pipe(terser())
            .pipe(rename({
                'extname': '.min.js'
            }))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('desktop/dist'));
    };
}
```

**What I've tried**:

1. Passing in options to @babel/preset-env, but all I get are a several **duplicate** lines of `var _typeof = require("@babel/runtime/helpers/typeof");` in the built code, which does nothing to resolve the aforementioned errors in IE.

   `'presets': [['@babel/preset-env', {
       'modules': false,
       'useBuiltIns': 'entry',
       'corejs': 3
   }]],
   'plugins': ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime']`
2. Passing in @babel/preset-env without any options:

   `"presets": ["@babel/preset-env"],
   "plugins": []`

But all this does is add the following to my code, and the `Symbol is undefined` error is still returned in IE.

```
function _typeof(obj) { "@babel/helpers - typeof"; if (typeof Symbol === "function" && typeof Symbol.iterator === "symbol") { _typeof = function _typeof(obj) { return typeof obj; }; } else { _typeof = function _typeof(obj) { return obj && typeof Symbol === "function" && obj.constructor === Symbol && obj !== Symbol.prototype ? "symbol" : typeof obj; }; } return _typeof(obj); }
```

Surely it must be easier than this?